# Is there a way to bypass downloading training data on SageMaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

When running a non-local instance on SageMaker like `ml.p3.2xlarge`, I can't use a local `file://` URI and must use `s3://` This makes sense, since it is a new instance.

However, when using the s3 URI for a 100GB dataset `tf_estimator.fit(s3://bucket/path/to/my/data)`
so I can use a larger non-local training instance, I have to wait around 10 minutes for the data to be downloaded from s3 to the instance.

It seems to be an issue even on the instances with quoted 10gig/second or faster connection.

Is there a way around this wait time which seems like it would become a severe problem with larger datasets?

Answer (score 0):

the delay is caused by multiple actions that need to be done when launching a training job, including provisioning the instances, downloading algorithm docker image, as well as downloading your dataset. SageMaker team is continuously improving the platform to reduce the latency. Meanwhile, if you are running your training job with deep learning frameworks, you can leverage the local mode feature to run your training job in your notebook instance when you are testing it. After that, you can launch the training job on a remote cluster to train your model against a large dataset.

To enable local mode, you simply specify the instance type to be "local" when you launch a training job in notebook instance. More details about local model can be found here: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk#sagemaker-python-sdk-overview